# SuggestedActions vs Keyboard in BotFramework?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

What is the difference between SuggestedActions and Keyboard class in BotFramework?

I am currently trying to run a waterfall where I present a question, user picks an option and I jump to the next step in the waterfall. I have implemented the buttons with suggested actions feature

```
const msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .text("Which pair?  \nExample: ETH BTC")
    .suggestedActions(
    builder.SuggestedActions.create(
        session, [
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "BTC USD", "BTC USD"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "ETH USD", "ETH USD"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "ETH BTC", "ETH BTC"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "XRP BTC", "XRP BTC"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "ZEC USD", "ZEC USD")
        ]
    ));
session.send(msg);
```

The same is also doable with Keyboard class

```
const msg = new builder.Message(session)
    .text("Which pair?  \nExample: ETH BTC")
    .addAttachment(new builder.Keyboard(session)
        .buttons([
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "BTC USD", "BTC USD"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "ETH USD", "ETH USD"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "ETH BTC", "ETH BTC"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "XRP BTC", "XRP BTC"),
            builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "ZEC USD", "ZEC USD")
        ]).toAttachment()
    )
session.send(msg);
```

How do I capture the response from this button in the next waterfall step or should I switch to using prompts instead. Also what is the difference between this and the keyboard class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SuggestedActions` is the replacement of `Keyboard` (e.g. [in C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/605eeceb36c01771d7146b39a6ec8b2184ad41a6/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/KeyboardCard.cs#L50) you will see they Keyboard related stuff marked as Obsolete).

To capture the response, you can send the suggested actions as part of prompt choice, as shown in the [feature-suggestedActions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/Node/examples/feature-suggestedActions) example.

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {

        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .text("Hi! What is your favorite color?")
            .suggestedActions(
                builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session,[
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "green", "green"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "blue", "blue"),
                        builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "red", "red")
                    ]
                )
            );
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, ["green", "blue", "red"]);
    },
    function(session, results) {
        session.send('I like ' +  results.response.entity + ' too!');
    }
]);
```